# Pass parameters to Spark Insert script

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

This must be a simple one but I'm stuck on it since quite some time.
I'm trying to pass parameters to my Insert script and the output for this is returning NULL. What am I doing wrong here? I'm writing this on Azure Databricks and this is a Python notebook.

```py
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DB.RUN_LOG (RunId INT, CreatedDate timestamp, Status string, ErrorDetail string)")
dfMaxRunID = spark.sql("select COALESCE(MAX(RunId),0) MaxRunId from DB.RUN_LOG")
vMaxRunId = dfMaxRunID.first()['MaxRunId']
vInsertRunId = vMaxRunId + 1
vFinal_CurrentTimeStamp = '2019-07-24 12:02:41'
print(vMaxRunId)
print(vInsertRunId)
print(vFinal_CurrentTimeStamp)
spark.sql("INSERT INTO TABLE DB.RUN_LOG values('vInsertRunId','vFinal_CurrentTimeStamp',null,null)")
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM DB.RUN_LOG").show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your insert statement below as:

```
>>> spark.sql("INSERT INTO TABLE DB.RUN_LOG values(%s,'%s','%s','%s')"%(vInsertRunId,vFinal_CurrentTimeStamp,'null','null'))
DataFrame[]
>>> spark.sql("SELECT * FROM DB.RUN_LOG").show()
+-----+-------------------+------+-----------+
|RunId|        CreatedDate|Status|ErrorDetail|
+-----+-------------------+------+-----------+
|    1|2019-07-24 12:02:41|  null|       null|
+-----+-------------------+------+-----------+



hive> select * from test_dev_db.RUN_LOG;
OK
1       2019-07-24 12:02:41     null    null
Time taken: 0.217 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Just checked- you need nulls in last two columns. so right statement would be as:

```
spark.sql("INSERT INTO TABLE db.RUN_LOG values(%s,'%s',null,null)"%(vInsertRunId,vFinal_CurrentTimeStamp))

>>> spark.sql("SELECT * FROM db.RUN_LOG").show()
+-----+-------------------+------+-----------+
|RunId|        CreatedDate|Status|ErrorDetail|
+-----+-------------------+------+-----------+
|    1|2019-07-24 12:02:41|  null|       null|
+-----+-------------------+------+-----------+

hive> select * from test_dev_db.RUN_LOG;
OK
1       2019-07-24 12:02:41     NULL    NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the below step is something wrong.

```
vMaxRunId = dfMaxRunID.first()['MaxRunId']
```

I suggest it to...

```
vMaxRunId = dfMaxRunID.select("MaxRunId").first()(0)
```

and then it will print an Id well.

Comment: Hi Lamanus, Thanks for the suggestion but if you check the screenshot above, I am able to get the value and print using vMaxRunId = dfMaxRunID.first()['MaxRunId']